# Column-wise min and max in new dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, max, min

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
sample<-c("A", "B", "C", "D")
x<-c(1,2,7,1)
y<-c(1,5,4,2)
df <- data.frame(sample,x,y)
```

and my desired output should be something like this:

```
  x y
min 1 1
max 7 5
```

I tried

```
df_min <- apply(df[, c(2,3)], 2, FUN = min, na.rm = TRUE)
df_max <- apply(df[, c(2,3)], 2, FUN = max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

but how do I get that into something that looks like my desired output dataframe?

Comment: `rbind(df_min,df_max)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `range`:

```r
data.frame(value = c("min", "max"),
           sapply(df[2:3], range))

  value x y
1   min 1 1
2   max 7 5
```

Or in `dplyr`:

```r
df %>% 
  summarise(across(-sample, range)) %>% 
  mutate(value = c("min", "max"), .before = 1)
```

---

If you wanna stick with `min` and `max`:

```r
data.frame(value = c("min", "max"),
           sapply(df[2:3], function(x) rbind(min(x), max(x))))
```

Comment: Or a bit simpler version of the 2nd option: `sapply(df[, 2:3], function(i) c(min = min(i), max = max(i)))`

Answer (score 0):

There's a fast implementation in `matrixStats::colRanges`.

```
t(matrixStats::colRanges(as.matrix(df[, 2:3])))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    7    5
```